# Translation help needed about terminology in optimization from Finnish to English

Tags: optimization, terminology

I am studying the course Mat-2.3139 in Aalto University and I need to find translations from Finnish to English for a few terms. Some of my teachers claim that they are missing funding for translations, not sure whether case here why they don't translate terms to make studying easier, so I am pretty much stucked before finding proper English terminology to research further. I am trying to find translations for the following terms and very happy if I can find related terminology in English:

> - täydennetyn lagrangen funktio
> - sisäpistemenetelmä
> - viivahaku

I need to do an algorithm to implement them but I cannot find references in English to cover the topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google translate translates sisäpistemenetelmä as "interior point method" and "viivahaku" as "line search".  I suspect both of those translations are perfect, as indeed "interior point method" and "line search" are key terms in optimization.

Google translate fails on the other one, but based on hhh's remark I suspect it's the "augmented Lagrangian method", though this could be wrong.

**Wikipedia**

- Augmented lagrangian method [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Lagrangian_method)
- Line search  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search)
- Interior point method [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_point_method).

Comment: Thank you +1, saving so much time with this :)

Comment: **Wikipedia:** Augmented lagrangian method [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Lagrangian_method). `"Line search"` is probably this one [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search). And interior point method [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_point_method).

Comment: @hhh That is true.

Answer (score 0):

I guess

- `"sisäpistemenetelmä"` to be `"interior point method"` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_point_method)
- `"täydennetyn lagrangen funktio"` means `"a lagrangean function"` and something like `"extended"` or something like that
- `"viivahaku"` means something like `"linear search"` or something like that, not sure here in the context of optimization